# postgresql fetch a row without knowing table detail infomation

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use ECPG - Embedded SQL in C - to fetch a row from a table using cursor.

for example:

```
struct{
   char *col1;
   char *col2;
    ....

}test_struct;

EXEC SQL DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR select * from test
EXEC SQL SET TRANSCATION read only
EXEC SQL OPEN mycursor
EXEC SQL FETCH FROM mycursor INTO :test_struct
```

but it seems I have to define a struct test_struct corresponding to table test, which means I have already know  how many columns in the table as well as their types and names . How can I fetch a row from any table which I didn't know its schema?

for example:

```
select * from arbitrary_table_in_my_db
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/// modified: SQLDA works fine, here is example code from http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4C206CD8.7050801@gmail.com

// have made some modification

```
#include <pgtypes_date.h>
#include <pgtypes_numeric.h>
EXEC SQL include sqlda.h;

sqlda_t         *sqlda1;

int
main(void)
{
        EXEC SQL CONNECT TO ....


        EXEC SQL DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM test;
        EXEC SQL OPEN cur;

        EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO BREAK;

        while (1) {
                /* Open a cursor and assign descriptor to the cursor  */
                EXEC SQL FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO DESCRIPTOR sqlda1;

                while (1) {
                  int i;
                  char name_buf[1024];
                  char var_buf[1024];

                  for (i=0 ; i<sqlda1->sqld ; i++) {
                    sqlvar_t v = sqlda1->sqlvar[i];
                    char *sqldata = v.sqldata;
                    short sqllen  = v.sqllen;

                    strncpy(name_buf, v.sqlname.data, v.sqlname.length);
                    name_buf[v.sqlname.length] = '\0';

                    strncpy(var_buf, sqldata, sqllen);

                    var_buf[sqllen] = '\0';


                    if(v.sqltype == 16)
                        printf("%s = %s, (type:%d)\n", name_buf, PGTYPESnumeric_to_asc((numeric*)sqldata,0), v.sqltype);
                    else if(v.sqltype == 18){
                        printf("%s = %s, (type:%d)\n", name_buf, PGTYPESdate_to_asc(*v.sqldata), v.sqltype);
                    }
                    else
                        printf("%s = %s, (type:%d)\n", name_buf, var_buf, v.sqltype);
                  }
                  printf("\n");

                  if ( sqlda1->desc_next==NULL )
                    break;
                }
        }
        EXEC SQL CLOSE cur;
        EXEC SQL COMMIT;
        EXEC SQL DISCONNECT ALL;
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: This might be of interest; it discusses how to read arbitrary `RECORD` results. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BAY115-F20EFAFF003B91E1FD30DE7AFD60@phx.gbl

Comment: Thanks Craig. But it still defined a specific struct to store the fetch result, my question is :Is is possible to fetch a row to a generic struct?

Comment: @caminio I don't use ECPG, but in general in Pg you'd want to convert the row to `xml`, `json` or `hstore` server-side and return it as a single field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SQLDA (SQL Descriptor Area) structure to retrieve information regarding the result set.

When using a descriptor in this way you can do statements like `SELECT *` and then use the SQLDA structure to find out details of what is actually being returned.

[SQLDA documentation (Postgresql 9.1)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/ecpg-descriptors.html#AEN42063)